# How can I send events to EventBridge upon AWS CloudWatch alarm status change?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, cloudwatch-alarms

How to send an Event to EventBridge on Alarm state change?

[Alarm events and EventBridge - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-and-eventbridge.html) says it's possible but doesn't tell how to.

UI Actions available on alarm also doesn't let EventBridge to be set as an action.

I don't want to use SNS. I need to trigger specifically via EventBridge.

Answer (score 3):

`EventBridge` cannot be a target for the Alarm. Instead, `EventBridge` is the bus that receives all the events from AWS (and optionally from AWS Partners and your custom events). That being said, in order to catch the Alarm from `Cloudwatch` into `EventBridge`, you have to go to:

`EventBridge`->`Rules`->`Create rule`

In `Event source`, choose `AWS events or EventBrige partner events`

In `Sample event` you can choose `CloudWatch Alarm State Change` so you can see a full list of values that you can use to filter your events.

In `Event pattern` you will choose:

`AWS services` -> `CloudWatch` -> `CloudWatch Alarm State Change`

This will create an Event pattern like this:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.cloudwatch"],
  "detail-type": ["CloudWatch Alarm State Change"]
}
```

You will want to set it for specific alarm and state, so you should add at least `resource` and `detail.state` sections, something like:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.cloudwatch"],
  "detail-type": ["CloudWatch Alarm State Change"],
  "resources": ["arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-1:123456789012:alarm:ServerCpuTooHigh"],
  "detail": {
    "state": {
      "value": ["ALARM"]
    }
  }
}
```